# Extracting data from a column with JSON data with the original dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have dataframe `df` as follows:

```
   API     sp_name               sp_input_params
getData   analytics.sp_1        {'req_url_query_params': [['@scroll_index', 'index']], 
                                 'req_body_params': [['@event_type_id', 'event_type_id']]}
getParam  analytics.sp_2        {'req_url_query_params': [['@athlete_guid', 'athlete_guid']], 
                                 'req_body_params': []}
```

Now I want to normalize the field `sp_input_params`. One of the way to achieve this as

```
df_final = pd.json_normalize(df['sp_input_params'])
```

But the above wont keep the other two columns viz `API` and `sp_name`. And I want to keep them along with the normalized one.

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use if default index in `df.index`:

```
df_final = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('sp_input_params')))
```

If not, use:

```
df_final = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('sp_input_params')).set_index(df.index))
```

Comment: What is this 'pop thing? I didn't know about the same. Secondly after extracting the JSON I am getting data in lists. Like `[['@scroll_index', 'index']]`. Is it possible to apply `lambda` on the resultant dataframe so as to make them `unlisted`? Third, what if I use more than 1 columns inside `pop`?

Comment: Here is used [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for used nad drop column from original. `Secondly after extracting the JSON I am getting data in lists` - What is expected ouput? No, multiple `columns` cannot be in `pop`

Comment: Expected output in plain string. And I have done that using `apply`. So how can I add multiple columns having JSON strings in it?

Comment: @pythondumb - Another idea is use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/35491399#35491399) solution

Comment: @pythondumb - Is possible add columns with json data to question like `pd.DataFrame(data)` ? And what is expected ouput from input data?